# Getting an error while trying to build an argument parser

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

Code I entered and error message:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True, help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh", help="type of preprocessing to be 
                 done, choose from blur, linear, cubic or bilateral")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Error Message:

```
####usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]
####ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
####An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
####SystemExit: 2
```

Comment: How are you providing the '--image' argument? Your code specifies `required`.  What's the command line?

Comment: Is this a `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: yes it is a jupyter note book

Comment: The use of `argparse` with a notebook has been discussed in other SO questions.  This is difficult, if not impossible.  When you start `jupyter` you are giving parameters, if any, to the server, not the notebook.  `argparse` is meant to Python scripts that are run by themselves, not ones that are embedded in a notebook or other interactive environment.