# Getting an error when building argument parser?

Tags: python, argparse

Code I entered and error message:

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
    help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh",
    help="type of preprocessing to be done")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

ERROR MSG:

```
usage: code for image_to_string for numbers.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]
code for image_to_string for numbers.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

N.B. `"image_to_string for numbers.py"` is the name of my file that I wrote this code on.

I am writing this in sublime, and running it on my terminal.

I found a very similar question where someone is using Jupyter, however I am not. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Here is the similar post: [Getting an error while trying to build an argument parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59531914/getting-an-error-while-trying-to-build-an-argument-parser)

Comment: The "error" is telling you that the `-i` (or `--image`) option is required...because you set `required=True` for that option in your argument parser. It seems to be working exactly as intended.

Comment: While there may be some readability improvements when calling the command if there are a *lot* of required arguments, for only one required argument I would just define `ap.add_argument('image', help='...')` and dispense with the option.

Comment: how are you specifying the `image` value when run the script?  What's the terminal command?

Answer (score 0):

Running your script in a BASH terminal:

```
1307:~/mypy$ python3 stack71767922.py 
usage: stack71767922.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]
stack71767922.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
```

the help:

```
0812:~/mypy$ python3 stack71767922.py -h
usage: stack71767922.py [-h] -i IMAGE [-p PREPROCESS]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i IMAGE, --image IMAGE
                        path to input image to be OCR'd
  -p PREPROCESS, --preprocess PREPROCESS
                        type of preprocessing to be done
```

running it with an `image` argument

```
0812:~/mypy$ python3 stack71767922.py --image a_path_name
{'image': 'a_path_name', 'preprocess': 'thresh'}
```

Run via a `jupyter` notebook it is hard to specify commandline arguments. But run in a terminal like this it is easy.  Some other frameworks (IDE, spyder etc), may require using a 'setup' window first.